# Multipart form POST with Content-Transfer-Encoding

Tags: php, post, apache2, multipartform-data

I have Apache2 server. I am trying to do post with multipart request.

```
-------boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_upload"; filename="some_file.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip
Content-Transfer-Encoding: BASE64

$base64_encoded_binary_file_content
-------boundary
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file_id"

1332-3443-7775-3433
-------boundary--
```

But on server part, at the time of file is uploaded and saved as TMP file, data are still base64 encoded. How to get this work?

Comment: post the html form and the code that's handling the upload.

Comment: I don't have any much code, if i am understanding right, server should automatic decode file. So file content on tmp file like "phpFGV442" should be already decoded or I am wrong?